# Ruby: Tests not running

Tags: ruby, unit-testing

I am attempting to run the following test:

```
require 'minitest/spec'
require 'minitest/autorun'

def test_true_is_true
  assert "3".is_a_number?
end
```

When I run this file I receive the following output:

```
Finished in 0.001183s, 0.0000 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.

0 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

How come none of my test are being ran?

Comment: Test methods are supposed to be in a class (which inherits from minitest::testcase or something)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a class that inherits from `MiniTest::Test` like this:

```
require "minitest/autorun"

class TestMe < Minitest::Test
  def test_true_is_true
    assert "3".is_a_number?
  end
end
```